# What's improper about the "improper (Riemann) integral"?

Tags: real-analysis

I can't seem to find an answer to this simple question, so I figured I'd ask it here.  Just why do we call the following "improper integrals"

$$\int_a^{+\infty} f(x)dx=\lim_{t\to +\infty} \int_a^t f(x)dx, \textrm{when } f \in \mathscr R\textrm{ on } [a,t], \forall t>a \textrm{, or}$$
$$ \int_a^b f(x)dx=\lim_{t\to b} \int_a^t f(x)dx, \textrm{when } f \in \mathscr R\textrm{ on } [a,t], \forall t\in(a,b)?$$

What's *improper* about them?  Is it that the limit may not converge even if $\int_a^t f(x)dx$ is well-defined for any valid $t$?  Or are we referring to the fact that the domain and/or the range of $f$ is unbounded?  Or some other reason?  Thanks a lot!  (My apology if this question is trivial or annoying to some folks.)

Comment: Improper, in this case, just means that you can't use the standard definition of the Riemann integral to get the value, but rather need a limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Improper, in these cases, just means that the standard definition of the Riemann integral, in terms of limits of finite partitions of the domain of the function into finite intervals, does not apply.

So we have a way of defining a Riemann integral, and then we extend it to cases that were not covered by the original definition using limits.

Comment: Something is missing in your first sentence.

Comment: perhaps he meant to end it with ", does not apply."

Comment: Yep, thanks. @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez